# How should I solve this integral?

Tags: integration

I want to solve the moment inertia of a ball. Rather than dividing the balls into many surfaces I divide the balls into many cylinders.
So I go
$$\int_0^R 4\pi r^3\rho \sqrt{R^2-r^2}dr$$
How to compute that?

Comment: You need to express your question in Latex (mathjax)... (Also,how can you divide a ball into cylinders?)

Comment: I almost did that but you beat me to it. Basically the balls are series of cylinders. The cylinder with the smallest r (r=0) has the height of 2 R. The largest cylinder has the height of 0.

Comment: I see (I think), you mean in a limiting sense, I presume?

Comment: Let $r = R\sin\theta$?

Comment: You are computing the moment of inertia, not the angular momentum...

Comment: Hmmm.... I suppose using θ would be easier to integrate. I just want to do it differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$I = \int_0^R r^3 \sqrt{R^2-r^2} dr$$Make the substitution $r = R \sin(x)$ and try to proceed. Move the cursor over the gray area for the complete solution. You can also use the substitution $R^2-r^2 = t^2$, to avoid some intermediate steps.

> We then get that $$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} R^3 \sin^3(x) \cdot R \cos(x) \cdot R \cos(x) dx = R^5 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^3(x) \cos^2(x) dx$$ \begin{align} \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^3(x) \cos^2(x) dx & = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2(x) \cos^2(x) \sin(x) dx\\ & = \int_0^{\pi/2} (1-\cos^2(x)) \cos^2(x) \sin(x) dx\\ & = \int_0^1 (1-t^2) t^2 dt = \dfrac13 - \dfrac15 = \dfrac2{15} \end{align}Hence, $$I = \dfrac{2R^5}{15}$$ and the answer to your question is $$\dfrac{8 \pi \rho R^5}{15}$$

Comment: WOW. I am very impressed. So yea coincidentally that sin x dx will be d (cos x)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try integrating by parts, since

$$\frac{d}{dr}(R^2-r^2)=-2r\,\,\,\,\,\text{, we can try}$$

$$u=r^2\;\;,\;\;u'=2r\\v'=r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}=-\frac{1}{2}(-2r)\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\;\;,\;\;v=-\frac{1}{3}(R^2-r^2)^{3/2}\;\;\;\;\;\Longrightarrow$$

$$\int\limits_0^R(r^2)r\sqrt{R^2-r^2}dr=\left.-\frac{1}{3}r^2(R^2-r^2)\right|_0^R+\frac{2}{3}\int\limits_0^Rr(R^2-r^2)^{3/2}dr=$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}r^4-\left.\frac{2}{15}(R^2-r^2)^{5/2}\right|_0^R=\ldots\text{etc.}$$